# Resizing image with PHP Imagick without the noise

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to downscale a JPEG image as follows:

```
$im = new Imagick('image.jpg'); // 625x625
$im->resizeImage(285, 285, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
$im->stripImage();
$im->writeImage();
```

The resulting image is downscaled but there's lots of noise around the text. Colours seem unaffected though - no pixelation.

So far I have tried the CAMCOM filter as well as changing the image compression to JPEG, LOSSLESSJPEG and ZIP. Using despeckleImage() doesn't do anything either.

Increasing the compression works, but when downscaling the same image in Fireworks with even less compression (80%), it gives a better result compared to the PHP solution.

Do I need to execute the lines of code in a particular order or does it not matter?

Is there anything else I can try to reduce/remove the noise whilst keeping the resulting file size as small as possible?

Comment: Very hard to suggest anything without seeing the image.

Comment: You're resizing an image to be quite small, that has text on it. I'd recommend trying using PNG  and reduce the colours in the image, rather than using JPG.